# How can I remove my previous Twitter name, so that it does not show in the search engines?

Tags: twitter

I have changed the name of my Twitter account, but the previous name still shows up in the web search, when I search my Twitter handle on a search engine.

How can I remove my previous Twitter name, so that it does not show in the search engines?

Answer (score 0):

yeah, you can-

1. more
2. Setting and privacy
3. your account
4. username
5. change and save it

***BTW you must have changed your name on your profile edit XD***

Comment: I know how to change my Twitter name, the fact is that my old name shows when I search my Twitter handle on search engines

Comment: do you mean that **@username** or what?

Answer (score 0):

Even after doing the steps above, your previous name will still show the same until updated by Google SEO/Web Console. You will have to be patient.

Comment: It has been a year or more ... I have filled the form for updating cache content, but it had no effect